# Thailand Overstay in 2015 - Can I re-enter?

Tags: thailand, overstaying

I'm looking to head back to Thailand for 25 days (under the 30 day allowance without a visa) in May 2018.

I last visited Thailand in June/July 2015 and had misjudged our timing out there and ended up overstaying for 2 days - we had only realised this once arriving back to BKK airport. We did not get asked to pay a fine, but had our passports stamped with a little scribble underneath.

My main query and concern is if I will be allowed to re-enter Thailand in May 2018 for 25 days due to staying 32 days instead of 30 back in 2015?

Answer (score 4):

You should **not** undergo any re-entry ban due to your previous 2-days overstay.

[This site](http://tratimmigration.com/overstay-warning/) sums it up very well:

> *An alien **who overstays more than 90 days** beyond his/her permitted date will be banned from re-entering the country for 1 year, starting from the departure date.*

[image: infographics on penalties]